# different connection string according to server name

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

I have a web based application (written in C#, asp.net). The app is being used by different companies. So, the connection string must be changed according to the company. What is the best way to alternate the connection string?

Note: I don't want to generate specific web.config file for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to alter `web.config` for different companies, one possibility is to provide it in format:

```
Server=DBHOST;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

and ask each company to add `DBHOST` entry in theirs [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29).

Answer (score 1):

If you host your website separately for each of those companies, using and changing the connection string **IS** the correct way. All the configuration information is there to be changed from one environment to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can give end user option to provide connection string dynamically like below.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionNumberOne"
    connectionString="Data Source=ds;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ConnectionNumberTwo"
    connectionString="Data Source=ds2;Initial Catalog=DB2;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

You can read the connection string thusly:

```
var connectionOne = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionNumberOne"];
var connectionTwo = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionNumberTwo"];
```

And you can save the connection string as well:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionNumberOne"].ConnectionString =        //CONCATINATE YOUR FIELDS TOGETHER HERE
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```